# User input in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark, input

I want to take date as user input in Pyspark but it is not as direct as it is in python with input() function so need help

I tried below code to take date as user input but it is not working so need your help to rectify it or know some other approach to take user input in Pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from datetime import date, datetime

def userip():
year = int(input('Enter a year: '))
month = int(input('Enter a month: '))
day = int(input('Enter a day: '))
d = date(year, month, day)
return d

convertUDF = udf(lambda z: userip())

convertUDF()
```

2nd Approach by using to_date :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date

spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("dateinput").getOrCreate()

date_input_str=input("Enter a date:")
date_input=to_date(date_input_str,'yyyy-mm-dd')
print("you entered:",date_input) 
spark.stop()
```

Output of above code is "Enter a date:" but not giving prompt to enter the value.

Comment: the UDFs are executed on the node side, so you can't ask for user inputs. ([see](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf:~:text=The%20user%2Ddefined%20functions%20do%20not%20take%20keyword%20arguments%20on%20the%20calling%20side.)). you could ask for inputs outside the function and pass the variables to the function.

Comment: indeed, it may be helpful to clarify for us (and yourself) why you want to accept user input in a spark program. The entire premise of spark is at odds with the concept of capturing user input. if this is a question of configuring tasks, you'd want to capture the user input before calling [spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html), or perhaps design a program around [spark connect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/quickstart_connect.html)

Comment: Hi Ben, actually I want to take date as user input and then use it in spark.sql("") query where I can use the table name in dynamic format based on user input. for e.g. if the dataset name is table_202212 so here I would need to take 202212  i.e. Dec2022 as user input and use it in table name i.e table_dateinput

Answer (score 0):

This could be one way to achieve user input and then passing that input to udf to do operations on dataframes.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf


sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


data1 = [
    ["01001", 1, 5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400],
    ["01004", 2, 1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400],
    ["01003", 1, 5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400],
    ["01004", 2, 1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400],
    ["01001", 43, 5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400],
    ["01003", 2, 1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400],
    ["01003", 1, 5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400],
    ["01001", 67, 1, 2, 300, -200, -300, 400],


      ]

df1Columns = ["county", "bin_number",   "age_group1",   "age_group2",   "t_group1_1",   "t_group2_1",   "t_group1_2",   "t_group2_2"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)

columns_list = list(df1.columns)
print(columns_list)



def take_input_and_broadcast():
    id_filter = input('Enter Id to filer: ')
    return id_filter


given_id = take_input_and_broadcast()



def mul_cond( county, binnumber, provided_id ):

    if county == provided_id:
        return binnumber * 1000
    else:
        return binnumber * (-1000)


mul_cond_udf = udf(mul_cond)

new_df = df1.withColumn("mul_cond_udf_value", mul_cond_udf(F.col("county"), F.col("bin_number"), F.lit(given_id)))

print("New column value added")
new_df.select(["county", "bin_number", "mul_cond_udf_value" ]).show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output is as follows:

```
Enter Id to filer: 01001
New column value added
+------+----------+------------------+
|county|bin_number|mul_cond_udf_value|
+------+----------+------------------+
|01001 |1         |1000              |
|01004 |2         |-2000             |
|01003 |1         |-1000             |
|01004 |2         |-2000             |
|01001 |43        |43000             |
|01003 |2         |-2000             |
|01003 |1         |-1000             |
|01001 |67        |67000             |
+------+----------+------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help but I want to use the user input in spark.sql("") query, please check below code.

df_spark= spark.sql(''' with temp1 as (
select * 
from library.dataset_yyyy_mm) select * from temp1""").show()

Comment: Just use f-strings in python to construct the query? Is the problem more complicated than that ?

Comment: Yes, actually what I want to do is to take date as user input  and then use that in spark.sql query

Code format:

1. Take date as user input with
2. Use that in Spark.sql("") query

but in 1st step I get error EOF error. I also tried using try except block but not working.

Comment: @adityakalkonde : update your question and include exact thing you want to happen.